# binning categorical variable based on specific bin size

Tags: r

I have a dataframe where each row of names I would like to divide into bins of specific size where each name can be a part of multiple different bins. However in the final binning each name can only be used once.

```
name <- c("James", "Terry", "Fred", "Scottie", "Clint", "Gary", "Kevin", "Harrison", "Patrick")
available_bins <- c("A/B", "A/B", "B", "C/D", "E", "A/D", "A/D", "D/C", "D/C")
init <- data.frame(name,available_bins)
init
#      name available_bins
#1    James            A/B
#2    Terry            A/B
#3     Fred              B
#4  Scottie            C/D
#5    Clint              E
#6     Gary            A/D
#7    Kevin            A/D
#8 Harrison            D/C
#9  Patrick            D/C
```

Each bin has a specific size and is stored in another dataframe.

```
bin_name <- c("A","B","C","D","E")
bin_size <- c(2,2,2,2,1)
binning_parameters <- data.frame(bin_name,bin_size)
binning_parameters
#  bin_name bin_size
#1        A        2
#2        B        2
#3        C        2
#4        D        2
#5        E        1
```

Each person should be put into a bin and there will always be enough bins of appropriate size to fit into.  For example, here you are given 9 people with four bins of size 2 and one bin of size 1.  Is there a way to efficiently do this (while respecting bin size)?  There doesn't necessarily have to be a single correct answer just something that allows all names to be put in the appropriate bins and size.

Example Result:

```
final_bin <- c("A", "B", "B", "C", "E", "A", "D", "C", "D")
final_bin <- data.frame(name,final_bin)
final_bin
#      name final_bin
#1    James         A
#2    Terry         B
#3     Fred         B
#4  Scottie         C
#5    Clint         E
#6     Gary         A
#7    Kevin         D
#8 Harrison         C
#9  Patrick         D
```

I've tried sorting by fewest number of people available for a bin and then iterating through by removing the remaining people from the set but the overlap between available bins means sometimes I am removing the wrong people between each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found no "tabular" approach (manipulating datatables, e.g. tidy style), but here's a recursive solution relying on list manipulation and {[purrr](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/index.html)} helpers:

- load packages:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
```

- create list of bins, each item with capacity (persons to hold) and members (to be gathered):

```r
bins <- setNames(1:5 |> imap( ~ list(capacity = c(2,2,3,2,1)[.y], members = list())),
                 LETTERS[1:5]
                 )
```

```r
#> bins
#> 
#> $A
#> $A$capacity
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> $A$members
#> list()
## plus four more list items (B-E)
```

- create list of persons, each with available bins and property `has_bin` which is set to `TRUE`, once the person has been given a bin:

```
persons <- setNames(c("A/B", "A/B", "B", "C/D", "E", "A/D", "A/D", "D/C", "D/C"),
                    c("James", "Terry", "Fred", "Scottie", "Clint", "Gary", "Kevin", "Harrison", "Patrick")
                    ) |> 
    map(~ list(available_bins = .x, has_bin = FALSE))
```

```r
#> persons
# $James
# $James$available_bins
# [1] "A/B"
# 
# $James$has_bin
# [1] FALSE
# 
# (plus 8 more items)
```

- a recursive function `collect_persons` which grabs persons per bin (by matching bin letter) until all bins are filled or all persons have been placed:

```
collect_persons <- function(bins, persons){
    ## exclude bins already filled:
    free_bins <- bins |> discard(~ {.x$capacity < 1})
    ## exclude persons already placed:
    free_persons <- persons |> discard(~ .x$has_bin)
    ## EXIT for lack of free bins or persons:
    if(!(length(free_persons) & length(free_bins))) return(bins)
    ## what's the label (letter) of the current free bin?
    this_bin_letter <- names(free_bins)[1]
    this_free_bin <- free_bins[[this_bin_letter]]
    ## how many persons can this free bin accomodate?
    bin_capacity = this_free_bin$capacity
    ## find candidate persons for a free_bin:
    person_index = grep(this_bin_letter, map_chr(free_persons, 'available_bins'))
    ## limit matches to current bin capacity:
    person_index = na.omit(person_index[1:bin_capacity])
    ## index of the first n persons to fill the bin's capacity n:
    candidate_names = names(free_persons)[person_index]
    ## add the indexed persons as bin members: 
    bins[[this_bin_letter]]$members = candidate_names
    ## mark these persons as already placed:
    persons[candidate_names] <- persons[candidate_names] |> map(~ modify_in(.x, 'has_bin', ~ TRUE))
    ## print(persons[candidate_names])
    ## mark the current bin as full:
    bins[[this_bin_letter]]$capacity = 0
    ## repeat until either all bins are full or all persons are placed:
    collect_persons(bins, persons)
}
```

- call the function and reshape the result into a dataframe:

```
data.frame(persons = collect_persons(bins, persons) |>
               imap('members', ~ .x) |> unlist()
           ) |>
    tibble::rownames_to_column('bin') |> ## package tibble required
    mutate(bin = substr(bin, 1, 1))
```

output:

```
  bin  persons
1   A    James
2   A    Terry
3   B     Fred
4   C  Scottie
5   C Harrison
6   C  Patrick
7   D     Gary
8   D    Kevin
9   E    Clint
```